# Client/Server game chat communication in Java

Tags: java, client-server, chat, reversi

I'm currently working on recreating Othello inside a terminal, and I need some help when it comes to determining whose move it is. I would like only one person to be able to type in their move at a time. Also it should send a message to each player telling whose move it is. The best way to implement this is to have two Scanners running in each application - one listening to the terminal and one to the keyboard. But how do I do this? Thanks. I referenced this, but I can't get it to work for some reason...I'm a little lost when it comes to the Protocol class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: I could give you a thousand links to examples, but what'd be the point? What are you having trouble with exactly?

Comment: how do i create a two way chat client within othello game that will only let one side type on command line at a time? At the same time, those commands will be interpreted by the game to determine pieces to flip.